# Have Noachides ever had their own semicha?

Tags: gentiles, noachide-laws, semicha, noahidism

Is there, or has there ever been, a concept of *semicha* among Noachides/Gentiles? That is, has there ever been a practice of granting *semicha* or similar ordinations to Noachides so that they can rule on matters concerning non-Jews as they relate to the Seven Laws?

To be clear, I do not know (and am not competent to propose) what an adequate educational or testing system would be for a practical Noachide semicha system today. If a Gentile semicha system ever existed before the present, I would suppose that it would be most likely to have existed only for a few generations after the Flood, while the Gentile nations still had a connection with Noah.

Comment: It is my understanding that a rabbi should always be consulted concerning questions on the Noahide Laws. After all, good knowledge and study in all areas of Jewish Law are needed to be able to decide what is forbidden/permitted under the Noahide Laws.

Comment: @ezra what did Noachides do between the giving of the Seven Laws and the giving of the Jewish law at Sinai? What did the grandchildren of Noah do if they weren't sure of whether something was allowed? Did they flip a coin? Did they ask Noah? If they asked Noah, then wouldn't that mean that Noah had *semicha*?

Comment: "The Giving of the Seven Laws." Hm. These laws were given at the Beginning of Creation. By the way, what makes you believe the people during Noah's time would have cared about the laws? They were evil and disobeyed G-d. And even if they did, why would you assume Noah would be their leader? I think you are trying to apply modern halacha to a very distant, ancient time.

Comment: @ezra The question would apply to those who learned in the Yeshiva of Shem and Ever. It would also apply to those who followed the halachos between Adam and Noah, ending with the family of Noah.

Comment: "If they asked Noah, then wouldn't that mean that Noah had _semicha_?" (from your comment). No, it'd mean he was knowledgeable. At least to me, "_s'micha_" implies a chain: A gives B _s'micha_, so B can give C _s'micha_.

Comment: @sabbahillel yes. I have always assumed that the line of patriarchs from Adam to Noah held some kind of authority, either due to birthright, appointment, or because of their particular righteousness. If Judaism has something to say on the nature of that authority - for example, if Lamech passed on some sort of ordination to his son Noah, the nature of that ordination, and what eventually happened to it, could be an answer. For example, maybe the line of ordination lasted to Heber, but Heber's son Peleg decided to worship idols and refused his father's ordination, so the line died out.